# Google Analytics data from previous days is not exported after using BigQuery Links

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

3 days ago I linked my Google Analytics 4 to my BigQuery using BigQuery linking from GA4 admin

[image]

but on my BigQuery I only find the events in the last 3 days

[image]

I have used GA4 in the last 8 months. Can I export all the events in the last 8 months to BigQuery? how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Google Analytics 4 BigQuery exporter **does not support backfilling**, so data will *only* stream into BigQuery from the point when you set it up.

[This article](https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-backfill-ga4-data-in-bigquery/) shows a way to load in historic data using a manual data transfer job, if you wish to explore this.